# CakePHP access 2nd level association data

Tags: cakephp, associations

I have **Transactions** that belong to a **Category** and can have one **Fuelup**. The **Fuelup**  belongs to a **Car** and a **Transaction**:

```
class Transaction extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Category');
    public $hasOne = array('Fuelup');
}

class Fuelup extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Transaction','Car');
}

class Car extends AppModel {
        public $hasMany = array('FuelUp');
}

class Category extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = "Transaction";
}
```

My tables look as follows:

```
transactions id|category_id|description
categories   id|name
cars         id|name|numberplate
fuelups      transaction_id|car_id|amount|mileage
```

In the index-function of the Transactions, I want to index all Transactions and also show, if existent, the Fuelup:

```
public function index() {
     $this->set('transactions', $this->Transaction->find('all'));
}
```

How can I access the car's name in this view? I can use $transaction['Fuelup']['car_id'] without problems, but cannot access $transaction['Fuelup']['Car'] or such.

I am running the latest version of CakePHP 2.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using recursive as specified by Hugo, you should look into the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior. You attach it in your `AppModel` like so:

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $recursive = -1; // disable recursive

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Then when you are doing your find, you can do this:

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    $transactions = $this->Transaction->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
            'Fuelup' => array(
                'Car'
            )
        )
    ));
    $this->set('transactions', $transactions);
}
```

Containable is much more efficient because it only grabs the data you specify, whereas recursive will bring back data you don't need, wasting resources.

Comment: I understand your approach and I found this solution by using the search aswell, but I cannot get it running. Where will I need to define that the fuelups should contain also their respective car?

Comment: You already have the necessary associations set up. If you want to go one level deeper and get the car as well, check out my edit. Is that what you mean? What do you mean by you can't get it running, do you get any errors?

Comment: I didn't set the AppModel Containable but just the TransactionsController. As the fuelup didn't act as Containable, I didn't get no car. Now it works like a charm, thank you very much for that!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the level of recursivity. You can do :

```
$this->find('all',array('recursive' => 2));
```

> The recursive property defines how deep CakePHP should go to fetch associated model data via find(), and read() methods.

See [this entry](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/models/model-attributes.html#recursive) from the Cook Book.

Comment: And to have it complete: If you want to use findById, you can use $this->Car->recursive = 2; $car = $this->Car->findById($id); to have the transaction data in the car's fuelups.